# Headers are not picking up from the Google sheet in Google big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a google sheet to my dataset in the google bigquery. Below are the settings
[Uploading configuration snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIK2J.png)

I have made the "Header rows to skip" = 1 and =0 as well

Result doesn't pick the header on the top. It shows "string_field_0"

Here is the file with just one header column and 3 values https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mnYBiDe-eOauhVa5QbM-BRelW2iwlhQD9lPMR50A9Lk/edit?usp=sharing

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error. Then I realized that I got it because all the columns are in string format. After adding a field in integer format the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

It is important to follow the steps from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#classic-ui_1).

We need to take care of:

1. Retrieving the Google Drive URI by getting shareable link.
2. Enabling Google Drive access, because accessing data hosted within Google Drive requires an additional `OAuth scope`. We can use following command to authenticate with Google Drive:

   `gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access`
3. Check if we are granted with required permissions and scopes. Finally, we can [create a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#creating_and_querying_a_permanent_external_table).

Keep in mind that for JSON or CSV files, you can check the Auto-detect option to enable schema auto-detect. **Schema auto-detection in the web UI is not currently supported for Google Sheets** (though it is available using the `bq` command-line tool and the API).

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.